# Can Logstash accept both Kafka and REST(HTTP) at the same time

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, elk

I am looking for something like this

```
input{
     tcp{
          port=>9600
          type=>sylog
        }
     kafka{
     bootstrap_servers=>"localhost"9092"
     topics=>["my_log"]
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would work, just fix your `bootstrap_servers` line to:

```
bootstrap_servers=>"localhost:9092"
```

It depends on your business logic, but generally I would recommend you to separate the inputs into two different files inside `/etc/logstash/conf.d`.

**input_tcp.conf**

```
input {
  tcp {
    port=>9600
    type=>sylog
  }
}
```

**input_kafka.conf**

```
input {
  kafka { 
    bootstrap_servers=>"localhost:9092"
    topics=>["my_log"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to implement this. thank you :)

Comment: I did try that however I am getting a logstash could not be started as there is already another instance running using configured data directory. you must change the path.data setting.

Comment: Please edit your question explaining what you tried and the exact error you get with stacktrace.